# Is it undefined behavior to run a member function in a separate thread, in parallel to the type's constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, race-condition, object-lifetime

This is a scenario you shouldn't ever do, but https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.cdtor#4 states:

> Member functions, including virtual functions ([class.virtual]), can be called during construction or destruction ([class.base.init]).

Does this hold if the functions are called in parallel? That is, ignoring the race condition, if the `A` is in the middle of construction, and `frobme` is called at some point AFTER the constructor is invoked (e.g. during construction), is that still defined behavior?

```cpp
#include <thread>

struct A {
    void frobme() {}
};

int main() {
    char mem[sizeof(A)];

    auto t1 = std::thread([mem]() mutable { new(mem) A; });
    auto t2 = std::thread([mem]() mutable { reinterpret_cast<A*>(mem)->frobme(); });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

---

As a separate scenario, it was also pointed out to me that it's possible for `A`'s constructor to create multiple threads, where those those threads may invoke a member function function before `A` is finished construction, but the ordering of those operations would be more analyzable (you know no races will occur until AFTER the thread is generated in the constructor).

Comment: "ignoring the race condition" ? The race condition is the core of the problem. If `t2` runs first there is no object to call a member function on

Comment: Yea that's a huge red flag. I guess I was thinking, if there was some magic synchronization primitive, where you could ensure `frobme` was executed after the first instruction of the constructor, would that be considered undefined behavior. This is coming from the perspective of static analysis.

Comment: maybe some trickery with locking/releasing a mutex in the constructors initializer list could make sure that construction started but is not finished by the time the member function is called

Comment: This code has another issue -- `reinterpret_cast<A*>(mem)` is not guaranteed to point to the object created by placement-new. You're meant to use the pointer "returned" by the placement-new .  Also, `mem` might not be aligned for `A` but I guess you omit that detail for brevity so we can disregard that point.

Comment: @M.M On a flat architecture, a pointer contains no info other than address. So `reinterpret_cast<A*>(mem)` is OK even though the std committee like to pretends it isn't. It's a big std issue that's hard to fix.

Comment: AFAIK just because a class is empty doesn't imply it can't have non trivial alignement requirement. In practice, such class has size 1 on common ABI, so it won't be an issue in that case in practice. It could be in theory.

Comment: What you violate in C++17 is just [\[class.mfct.non-static\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mfct.non-static#2). There is definitely no data race here, because data race happens when you have multiple unsynchronized accesses (reads or writes) to the same memory location, at least one of which is a write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues here: your specific code and your general question.

In your specific code, even in the best possible case scenario (where `t2` executes after `t1`), you have a data race due to the lack of synchronization between creation and use. And that makes your code UB regardless of the order of execution.

In the general question, let's assume that the constructor of a type hands the `this` pointer off to some other thread, which then calls functions on it, and the hand-off itself is properly synchronized. Would some other thread invoking a member function be considered a data race?

Well, it certainly would be a data race if the other thread invokes a function that reads member values or other data written by the constructor subsequent to the point of the hand-off, or if the constructor accesses members or other data written by the member function being invoked. That is, if there are no data races between the code being executed simultaneously.

Assuming that neither of those is the case, then everything should be fine (mostly. It's possible to define `A` in such a way that your `reinterpret_cast` doesn't return a usable pointer to the `A` you created in that storage; [you'd need to `launder` it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382728/734069)). An object under construction/destruction can be accessed, but only [in certain ways.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.cdtor) Stick to those ways, and you should be fine... with one possible catch.

There's nothing in the standard about data races on the completion of an object's initialization, only on conflicts in memory locations. Once the object is fully constructed, the behavior of `virtual` functions could change, based on changing vtable pointers and such if the dynamic type is a class derived from the class given to the other thread. I don't believe there's a clear statement about this in the section on the object model.

Also, note that C++20 added a special rule to [class.cdtor](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.cdtor#2):

> During the construction of an object, if the value of the object or any of its subobjects is accessed through a glvalue that is not obtained, directly or indirectly, from the constructor's `this` pointer, the value of the object or subobject thus obtained is unspecified.

Comment: I think @Ben Voight's answer regarding glvalues is key in this case. It's UB to use any glvalue of the object before lifetime has started, for non-static member functions. Using `this` in the constructor/initializer list is okay because it is a prvalue.

Comment: @MikeLui: `this` is a prvalue, yes, but it's a value which is a *pointer*. Dereferencing a pointer creates... a glvalue. And it's through that glvalue that you access the object. This is *why* the section he referened had a *specific exception* for objects under construction/destruction.

Comment: @MikeLui your comment is incorrect -- see my first comment under Ben's answer. For an object under construction, the behaviour is covered by class.cdtor, and not by the bullet points under basic.life/6 which are introduced by the word "Otherwise"

Comment: @M.M: in code executing concurrently with placement-new (as this question has), it is not known whether the object is preconstruction, under construction, or fully constructed.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't want to repeat the discussion under your answer here . In Nicol's answer it addresses a hypothetical code where it is known that the object is under construction (see the third paragraph of this answer)

Comment: _"you have a data race due to the lack of synchronization between creation and use"_ I don't think this is called [data race](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.races#def:data_race). Because there is no read or modification here.

Comment: In all common arch, all bits of a ptr are used to represent the addr value, and you don't need to launder it, technically. (It practice, you do. But this is a LL q.)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Lifetime race?

Answer (score 3):

Besides the race condition (which you might be managing with mutexes or similar), you're subject to the usual limitations on an object whose lifetime has not yet started, namely:

> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways.

See [`[basic.life]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6) for the full list of operations that are and are not allowed.

In particular, one of the restrictions is that

> The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> ...
>
> - the glvalue is used to call a non-static member function of the object

which clearly forbids your example.

Also `[class.cdtor]` says:

> For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior

and even if you do synchronize to some event triggered after construction begins, [this rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#2) will forbid that code:

> During the construction of an object, if the value of the object or any of its subobjects is accessed through a glvalue that is not obtained, directly or indirectly, from the constructor's `this` pointer, the value of the object or subobject thus obtained is unspecified

Comment: What about the "For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor]." part? That's kind of important here, since that's precisely the case under discussion.

Comment: Immediately after your first quote, it says "For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor]. Otherwise, ".  And your second quote is part of that "Otherwise" and therefore not applicable since we are talking about the case of an object under construction .  In fact the case you lay out here would imply that no constructor can call any member function

Comment: @M.M: There is no happens-before relationship between the construction and the member function call, so the object is not guaranteed to be under construction.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Then it's UB because of a data race, so this section doesn't even apply.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Covered in the first parenthetical of my answer, which was there in the very first version.

Comment: This is a bit confusing to me because according to [basic.life]: this is undefined before the lifetime of `o` starts, where the lifetime begins when "initialization" is complete. Initialization is vague and points to [dcl.init], which says an object may be default initialized, where the default constructor may be called. The default constructor is able to call member functions as per [class.cdtor]. So it is both defined and undefined, depending on what "initialization" means. Can you clarify what initialization means in [basic.life]?  Apologies for lack of links in comment

Comment: @MikeLui: Initialization is complete when the first non-delegating constructor of the most derived class finishes.  I'll look for a reference for that.

Comment: @MikeLui: Initialization is described by the entire section [dcl.init]. This is not a short section.

Comment: @BenVoigt If the constructor has started but not finished, then the object is under construction . This is inextricably linked to the race condition; if you say "besides the race condition" then the following text can only apply to the situation of the race happening to fall out such that the constructor had started.  IOW I agree that the quoted text prevents calling a member function before the constructor has started, but that is already covered by pointing out the race condition

Comment: @M.M: What if instead of passing these two lambdas directly to `std::thread`, a wrapper is used that takes a global lock?  Then the two function calls cannot overlap, preventing the data race... but you still do not know which happens first.  There is no guarantee here that construction has begun, and providing that requires stronger synchronization than merely resolving the data race.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But then you're talking about a hypothetical scenario, not the given code. And that hypothetical scenario wouldn't even be addressing the question which is *specifically* about the period during construction.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Maybe the mutex is released temporarily during construction (e.g. by waiting on a condition variable).  Then the other thread could execute mid-construction with no data race.  What I'm saying is that adding a mutex to solve the data race is not enough.  The question specifically said to not worry about the data race which tells me that I can rely only on the minimum necessary changes to remove the data race, and not on any other change (like strong ordering between beginning of construction and the member function call)

Comment: @BenVoigt: "*this rule will forbid that code:*" That's interesting, because C++17 [doesn't have that rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.cdtor).

Comment: Switched the "marked answer" because I think the parts referenced in the above answer, while very helpful, aren't as specific to the scenario in my question. The redirection to [class.cdtor] means that the above quotes are less relevant.

Comment: @NicolBolas _"Then it's UB because of a data race"_ There is no data race here. By [the definition of data race](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.races#def:data_race).