# In-place new + reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, c++17

The code below compiles, but I am not 100% sure that it conforms to the standard:

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    uint8_t m_storage[sizeof(A)];
    
    new (m_storage) A();
    
    auto deleter = [](A * p) { p->~A(); };
    std::unique_ptr<A, decltype(deleter)> p(reinterpret_cast<A *>(m_storage), deleter);
    
    p->x = 0;

    return p->x;
}
```

Is it a proper usage of `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: If you can, prefer capturing the pointer produced by the placement new expression. It will take less lawyering.

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of std::launder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382501/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdlaunder)

Comment: @IlCapitano Did you mean `std::launder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct reinterpret cast.

Albeit not correctly aligned storage. And potentially wrong placement new (should cast parameter to `void*`).

Comment: Looks like it can be `alignas(A) uint8_t m_storage[sizeof(A)];`

Comment: Better would be to use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) instead, eg: `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(A), alignof(A)> m_storage;`  Or, if you need an array of `A`s: `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(A), alignof(A)> m_storage[N];`