# Can I overwrite a const object via placement-new?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdlaunder

[Basic.life/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8) tells us that we can use the storage occupied by an object to create a new one after its lifetime has ended and use its original name to refer to it unless:

> - **the type of the original object is not const-qualified**, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static data member whose type is const-qualified or a reference type, and [...]

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

But, just below that we can see a note saying that:

> - If these conditions are not met, a pointer to the new object can be obtained from a pointer that represents the address of its storage by calling `std​::​launder`

This explains [the purposes of `std::launder`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39382501/7151494). We can have a class type that has `const` members and use placement-new to create a new object there with different internal values.

What surprises me is the first part of the first quote. It clearly indicates that if the storage is `const` (not necessarily contains `const` members, but the whole object is declared as `const`), we cannot use it to refer to a new object as is, but it may imply that `std::launder` may fix it.

But how would we create such object? The simplest example fails:

```
const auto x = 5;
new (&x) auto(10);
```

It's because we cannot use `const void*` as a buffer for placement-new. We could `const_cast` it, but casting away a "true" `const`ness is Undefined Behaviour. I believe this is also the case here.

I would understand if there simply was a prohibition of using `const` objects as placement-new buffer, but if that would be the case, what would be the purpose of the emphasised part of the first quote? Can we use reuse a truly `const` object's storage for a different object?

Comment: If the original object is `const` it is undefined behavior if you modify it. Compiler might put such objects in read-only memory or assume that the value never change. If the first case you would get a write access violation while in the second, the compiler might use the value it determine at compile time as it has the right to assume that such object never changes.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/ptr.launder#example-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently all it took was to look *just* 2 items below the part of the standard I linked to. [Basic.life/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#10) tells us that:

> Creating a new object within the storage that a const complete object with static, thread, or automatic storage duration occupies, or within the storage that such a const object used to occupy before its lifetime ended, results in undefined behavior.

And it comes with an example:

```
struct B {
  B();
  ~B();
};

const B b;

void h() {
  b.~B();
  new (const_cast<B*>(&b)) const B;     // undefined behavior
}
```

which ultimately leads me to a conclusion that **it's illegal to use *placement-`new`* on a memory occupied by a truly `const` object**. Thus, I believe that the note mentioned in the question (in reference to point [8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8)) is faulty - it should exclude the case in question.

Comment: What if `B b` is not `const` but has a `const ` member? I.e. `struct B { const int x; ... }`

Comment: @DanM. not an issue. You can do that.

Answer (score -1):

A const object can have non const pointers to its location.

```
struct bar{ int x=5; };
struct foo{
  const bar b;
};
foo f;
::new (&f) foo{{3}};
```

here I have a const int `f.b.x` which I destroy and construct a new one with value 3.

```
char buff[sizeof(foo)];
foo const* pf=::new(buff)foo;
foo const* pf2=::new(buff)foo{{3}};
```

Might also be able to do it with unions.

Comment: This example doesn't refer to the emphasised quote. It refers to the next part, which mentions a *class type that contains a non-static data member whose type is const-qualified*. Make `f` a `const foo` and the code does not compile. This is what I was asking about. If I made myself unclear, may I please ask for an edit to my answer which would make it more clear?

Comment: There is a const bar now at the same address.  Type changed.  Added a placement new as well.  The core is that a const object storage can have a non const pointer to its memory.