# Copy-assignment operator on object with const member

Tags: c++, c++11

This one has been bugging me for years.

Given a class:

```cpp
class Foo
{
    const int value;

public:
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& copy_from)
};
```

How should I implement copy-assignment for a class that has a const member variable? The only options I have come up with are:

A) Use placement-new in the assignment operator:

```cpp
class Foo
{
    const int value;

public:
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& copy_from)
    {
        if (this != &copy_from) {
            new (this) Foo(copy_from);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

B) Make the member variable non-const:

```cpp
class Foo
{
    int value;

public:
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& copy_from)
    {
        if (this != &copy_from) {
            value = copy_from.value;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Is there another option? I love the `const` keyword and would hate to see it go.

Yes, this is a trivial class and default constructors/operators are in play. Set that aside please.

Comment: If you have two options and one involves removing "const" which you don't want, why don't you use the other option?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's actually valid to modify an object that's implicitly constant in this way. Would need to see what the standard says about it. It might be okay, since the original is destructed and a new object constructed in its place.

Comment: @paddy Answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69276413/3966456)

Comment: `const` has its value, but I don't love it nearly as much as you do.   Since it is a `private` member and you want to change it in an  assignment operator for the class, I would leave `const` off the declaration of `value`.

Comment: "Is there another option?" You can wrap the field in a proxy class and modify the value via a passkey. I don't think it's worth the trouble in practice.

Comment: If you use placement new and your real-world class has virtual functions a derived class will give you all sorts of problems.

Comment: B) is the consensus you'll find. const and reference non-static data members are usually not a good idea.

Comment: If the value of `Foo::value` can meaningfully change during the lifetime of a `Foo` object - via copy assignment or otherwise - then it has no business being `const`. If it shouldn't change - if the member is well and truly constant - then implement your copy assignment in a way that leaves it unchanged. Pick one. Set aside implementation details for a moment - those come later. First, clarify your design for the class, figure out what invariants you wish to maintain.

Comment: Why is value const? It's private to the class, so only the class methods can change it. What's the use case here?

Answer (score 0):

I asked for recommendations, and I got them.  I am reducing my usage of the beloved `const` keyword based on everyone's input and favoring option B.

I don't like it, but it seems to more correctly conform to [canonical C++ recommendations](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#10) in addition to public consensus.  That's good enough for me.