# How to check out-of-range when using placement new operator?

Tags: c++, c++17, valgrind, placement-new

In the following code

```
struct alignas(8) SimpleChar {
    SimpleChar(char c_) : c(c_) {}

    char c;
};

int main() {
    char slab[10] = {'\0'};
    // call to 'SimpleChar::SimpleChar(char)' too

    SimpleChar* c0 = new (slab) SimpleChar('a'); 
    SimpleChar* c1 = new (slab + 8) SimpleChar('b');
    SimpleChar* c2 =
      new (std::launder(reinterpret_cast<char*>(slab + 80))) SimpleChar('d');  // But how to detect the wrong usage?
    std::cout << c2->c << std::endl;                                           // d

    SimpleChar* c3 = new (slab + 180) SimpleChar('e');  // But how to detect the wrong usage?
    std::cout << c3->c << std::endl;                   // e
}
```

`c2` and `c3` are constructed in a wrong place. But how to detect it?
In this case, both **valgrind** and `-fsanitize=address` don't work.

I'm wondering how to detect such wrong usage?

Comment: *But how to detect it?* -- So basically your code is just a fancy way to do a buffer overrun?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? GCC is complaining about the code a lot: https://godbolt.org/z/on3735P6q

Comment: You should not try to detect the case on executing the placement new, but already *before*: `size_t indexToInsert = ...; if(indexToInsert < std::size(slab)) { /* can safely construct a new element */ } else { /* out of range – some appropriate error handling */ }`

Comment: Note that `std::size` only works as intended as long as you have direct access to the `slab` array – once decayed to a pointer (e.g. due to passing it to a function) you won't get the desired result any more. `std::array` is safer in this respect (on passing to functions do so by reference!).

Comment: By the way, about laundering: You'd have to launder the new `cN` pointers, not the memory address passed to the placement new...

Comment: @Aconcagua They don't need any `std::launder`ing either, since they come from `new`.

Comment: @user17732522 [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382728/1312382) says differently (if I read it right) – at least `new` is not the reason for why we can skip laundering, instead possibly other circumstances listed in [\[basic.life\].8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8) (reference from cited answer) – not going to validate the specific case against, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua That applies specifically if you _don't_ use the pointer returned from `new` to access the object. `new` is specified to return a pointer to the newly created object. You could say it performs the laundering for you when returning. If OP tried to access the `new`ed object through `slab`, then yes, `std::launder` (after the cast) would be necessary (the condition in [basic.life]/8 does not apply).

Comment: @user17732522 So obviously I didn't read right ;) Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Isn't `c0` and `c1` also constructed in a wrong place?

Comment: Just enable the compiler warnings and you will detect it ^^ Moreover I think there is a misunderstanding, `alignas` does not accept a size in bits, but in bytes (the same goes for the pointer arithmetic), so all your placement-news are invalid and UB. And the compiler warnings catch them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c1` is also placed incorrectly. The size of `SimpleChar` must be at least `8` because of the `alignas(8)`. So at offset `8` into the array there isn't enough space for one anymore.

Based on the options you showed, I assume you use GCC or Clang.

In that case `-fsanitize=undefined`, specifically `-fsanitize=alignment`, may complain because the offsets in your example are misaligned for the type.

In fact, generally all of your placement-news have UB, because it isn't guaranteed that `slab` is aligned to `8`. You'll need to add `alignas(SimpleChar)` to its declaration as well if you want to store `SimpleChar`s in it.

On Clang `-fsanitize=undefined`, specifically `-fsanitize=array-bounds`, will also complain for access out-of-bounds on the storage array.

GCC doesn't seem to support the `array-bounds` UB sanitizer check, but instead complains with a warning included in `-Wall`, specifically `-Wplacement-new`.

(Also, technically, an array that is used to provide storage for other objects should have element type `unsigned char` or `std::byte`, not `char`.)

Comment: Thank you for you help.The -fsanitize=undefined and -fsanitize=alignment help check it.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind memcheck intercepts and validates heap allocation and deallocation functions.

The placement new operator is not such a function.

So what matters is the memory provided to placement new. Memcheck does not perform bounds checking on stack memory (unless the access is way off). @user17732522 seems to have answered for LLVM sanitizers.