# Placement new + reinterpret_cast in C++14: well-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing

Consider the following example in C++14:

```
alignas(T) unsigned char data[sizeof(T)];
new (data) T();
T* p = reinterpret_cast<T*>(data);
p->something();  // UB?
```

Is this code legal, or are the Strict Aliasing rules being violated, since `unsigned char*` may not be aliased by `T*`? If it's legal, what parts of the Standard explicitly say so?

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) has a similar example which claims `std::launder` must be used in C++17. What does this mean for C++14, where we don't have `std::launder`?

```
    // Access an object in aligned storage
    const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const
    {
        // Note: std::launder is needed after the change of object model in P0137R1
        return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data[pos]));
    }
```

Comment: It was impossible to do legally in C++14 and before, but the compilers never enforced (and still don't enforce, AFAIK) that outside of a few narrow cases, so nobody cared.

Comment: `std::launder()` wasn't added even though everything was working well in C++14. :-)   Also, `new` is returning a valid pointer to what it creates. Why not just save that?

Comment: You are correct that you must launder the reintepreted pointer. However, if you can afford to, it might be worth storing the original pointer returned by placement new, thereby avoiding relaundering for every access, which may or may not prevent optimisation opportunities.

Comment: There is a `T` object at memory location pointed by `data`, therefore aliasing rule has nothing to do with it. `std:launder` is needed due to lifetime rules, where `data` does not have to be "updated" to point to constructed object - so it is matter of optimization and fixing reachability analysis - after laundering `T` is reachable via the returned pointer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of std::launder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39382501/430766)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your replies! I will try to answer the question combining the knowledge I've gotten from the responses.

**There is no Strict Aliasing violation**

As per [basic.life#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.life#2):

> The lifetime of an array object starts as soon as storage with proper size and alignment is obtained, and its lifetime ends when the storage which the array occupies is reused or released

Therefore, after the placement `new` call, the `char` array no longer contains objects of type `char`. It contains a newly created object of type `T`.

Later, we access the object of type `T` via a `T*`, which is a valid alias. Therefore, Strict Aliasing rules are not violated here.

**Lifetime**

The **real** problem is **lifetime**. When we `reinterpret_cast<T*>(data)`, we are using a pointer (`data`) that points to expired data, since it has been replaced by the new object. There is no guarantee that the `data` pointer is "updated" to point to the newly-created object.

- In C++14, the only way to do this legally is by accessing the object `T` via the pointer returned by placement `new`.
- In C++17, additionally, we can access the object via the old pointer, `data`, **as long as** we launder it via `std::launder`. This allows not having to store the pointer returned by placement `new`.

Answer (score 3):

Yup. As you figured out, this is a case where you need C++17 `std::launder`. What it means for C++14 is that you need to store the return value of `new`, even if that brings some overhead.

This isn't exactly a surprise. One reason why `std::launder` was introduced, and all the associated changes to C++17 are justified, is because of the overhead you see in C++14.

Note that this overhead didn't really materialize a decade ago, because it's mostly missed-optimizations overhead. It only started to count when optimizers started to get smarter. The flip side is that illegal code like in this question did not tend to break in old compilers, even though it was never legal.

Comment: I haven't heard of any compilers yet performing optimizations in this kind of situation based on the absence of `launder`, and when they eventually implement them, I really doubt they're going to apply them in C++14 and force all the C++14 code bases to store the return value of `new` despite the overhead. I would say in C++14 mode you can just pretend the pointer-interconvertibility restrictions don't exist.

Comment: The part that I find confusing is that the Strict Alising rule talks about "read or modify the **stored value** of an object". Also when calling placement new, a new object is created on storage. So the question is: do the Strict Aliasing rules apply in this case? Is the char array still a simple char array after placement new, or does it become the new object T?

Comment: In other words, https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.life#2 says that the lifetime of the raw array ends when its storage is reused. So in that case, after placement new, we don't really have a plain char array anymore, but actually an object of type T? And in that case we would be accessing the object as we should, via a T&?

Comment: @user1011113: The Standard may view the lifetime as ending implicitly when storage gets reused, but that abstraction model creates a huge gulf between the range of optimizations that will almost always handle correctly all cases that actually arise, and those that will handle all corner cases that could possibly arise, and thus doesn't actually match the way clang and gcc actually behave.

Comment: Essentially I would like to understand what part of the Standard the code violates: 1) Strict Aliasing rules, 2) Lifetimes (pointer to re-used storage whose lifetime ends), or both? @MSalters could you clarify?

Answer (score -3):

The other answers and comments have already addressed the well-formedness issue. However, you can avoid this issue entirely;
you can make use of the fact that the placement-`new` operator returns a valid pointer to a `T`. So instead of writing:

```
new (data) T();
T* p = reinterpret_cast<T*>(data);
```

You could write:

```
T* p = new (data) T();
```

So `std::launder()` is not necessary at all in this case, and this is valid code in C++14 and earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately in my use case, storing the pointer returned from placement new may have a non-negligible impact on memory footprint. The use case is similar to static_vector: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage

Comment: @user1011113 Whatever the impact of  `new` on memory is, happens right when it returns. Discarding the return value does not optimize anything. You need explain in more details why you don't use the return of `new`. If you think placement allocates memory, you need to reread your book.

Comment: @Red.Wave If you make a static vector kindof thing, then you have one large buffer and a bunch of small objects allocated to that buffer that you later want to random-access. Storing all these pointers will kill performance in all manner of ways. Frankly, this is an open problem that (to my knowledge) has no satisfying solution in current C++.

Comment: op isnt asking "how to do this?" but "is this code legal?". That one can avoid to write OPs code and write other code instead is not answering the question.

Comment: If you know the layout beforehand, then a single pointer to layout is enough, provided that you know howto do lazy initialization. If you don't know the layout until runtime, you are doomed to create one pointer per object. In either case, you need a lot of stuff in the OP.