# which case is the std::launder necessary to avoid UB

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider this case

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct NonImplicitLifetime{
    NonImplicitLifetime(){}
    ~NonImplicitLifetime(){}
};
int main(){
   // case 1:
   auto ptr = (NonImplicitLifetime*) malloc(sizeof(NonImplicitLifetime)*2); // #1
   auto second = ptr+1;
   new (second) NonImplicitLifetime{};
   *second;   // #2

   // case 2:
   unsigned char buff[sizeof(NonImplicitLifetime) * 2]; // #3
   auto ptr_second = buff + sizeof(NonImplicitLifetime); 
   new (ptr_second) NonImplicitLifetime{};
   *(NonImplicitLifetime*)ptr_second; // #4
}
```

In C++ 20, `malloc` can implicitly create the array of 2 `NonImplicitLifetime`, and `second` points to the second element of the array, the use `new` to create an object in that storage, IIUC, `second` should points to the new created object and `std::launder` is not necessary.

[intro.object] p2

> If an object is created in storage associated with a member subobject or array element e (which may or may not be within its lifetime), the created object is a subobject of e's containing object if:
>
> > - the lifetime of e's containing object has begun and not ended, and
> > - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location associated with e, and
> > - the new object is of the same type as e (ignoring cv-qualification).

In case 2, since the element of the array is of type `unsigned char`, the new created object is not the subobject of the array, the array just provides storage according to [intro.object] p3, that is, `ptr_second` still points to a subobject of type `unsigned char` whose lifetime has ended. Does it mean we must use `std::launder` to acquire the pointer pointing to the new created object from `ptr_second`, which is necessary?

Comment: `*ptr_second; // #4` is `unsigned char`. Where do you want to apply `std::launder`?

Comment: You change the type of the object in the storage, the launder is necessary. The related post or even the dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382501/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdlaunder

Comment: Interesting (theoretical) question about the array element, but I'm not sure the standard authors know the answer themselves, those rules have always been wonky. I'd use `std::launder` just in case; it should be rare for it to actually make a difference, so it's not like you're losing optimization opportunities here.

Comment: It isn't clear how you would use `std::launder` here. Note that it is a precondition to `std::launder<T>(p)` that an object of type similar to `T` already exists at the address represented by `p`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Isn't an object created by `new-expression` that is of type `T` at `p` in the example?

Comment: `second = new (second) NonImplicitLifetime{}` would avoid use of `std::launder`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I know that but I don't want to talk about how to correctly write code, instead, just a theoretical question about C++ object model.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `std::launder` is necessary.

I don't even see how the type being non-implicit-lifetime or the specific `new` construction would matter.

`buff` after array-to-pointer decay always points to a `unsigned char` element of the array. That element, or another array elements obtained by pointer arithmetic, is never pointer-interconvertible with any other object. So `std::launder` is always necessary to get a pointer to an object other than one of the array elements.