# Can I delete object itself and reallocate it?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, this

Can I reallocate object itself?

Recently i studied about copy constructor and i get curious about deleting 'this' and reallocating it.

```
obj(const obj &s) {
    if(this != NULL)
        delete this;
    this = new obj();
}
```

And it says [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment.
Is it impossible to reallocate itself? if so, why is that?

Comment: `this` is a prvalue, so you can't assign a value to it. It would be the same as trying to do `0 = 10;`.

Comment: I think you can call the destructor explicitly and than do a placement new, that said, ain't a good idea to surprise your callers by such a behavior

Comment: Relevant [Is it allowed to call destructor explicitly followed by placement new on a variable with fixed lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42598915/is-it-allowed-to-call-destructor-explicitly-followed-by-placement-new-on-a-varia).

Comment: FYI if you want to do so, some non-standard optimizations can't work, for example: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fstrict-vtable-pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` operator works only for objects allocated using operator `new`, otherwise behavior is undefined.

Once `delete this;` is done, none of the members should be accessed. If accessed, it will cause exception and leads to crash.

But you cannot assign to `this` pointer. `this` is a **prvalue** expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called.